# Switching between pan and orbit while holding MMB

Tags: interface, 3d-view, linux

In previous versions of Blender I've used, pressing or releasing <kbd>Shift</kbd> while holding <kbd>[image: MMB] MMB</kbd> would switch between orbiting and panning, without needing to let go of <kbd>[image: MMB] MMB</kbd>. In my fresh installation of Blender 2.77 (on Ubuntu Linux 16.04), pressing or releasing <kbd>Shift</kbd> while holding <kbd>[image: MMB] MMB</kbd> does nothing; if I wasn't holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> when I pressed down <kbd>[image: MMB] MMB</kbd>, then it would stay in orbit mode, no matter what. How would I restore the old behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Borrowed from:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/187781/143201

This is verified working in Blender 3.0.1 and involves changing the keymap: [image: keymap]

- Go into `Edit` -> `Preferences` -> `Keymap`
- Search for `view3d.rotate` and find the one bound to Mouse / Middle Mouse
- Under View3D Rotate Modal, click `Add New`
- Pick `Switch to Move` from the list
- Expand the tiny ▶ next to `Switch to Move` (if you try and do it on the <kbd>A</kbd> just to the right without expanding, it won't let you pick <kbd>Shift</kbd>)
- Click the <kbd>A</kbd> next to `Switch to Move` and press <kbd>Left Shift</kbd>
- Pick `Press` from the drop-down to its right

Now repeat the process for `view3d.pan`, `Switch to Rotate`, and `Release`

Answer (score 0):

This is a setup that works great in Blender 3.6.5 and solves the problem of not getting stuck moving when you release the <kbd>Middle Mouse</kbd>.

Go to Blender *Preferences > Keymap > 3D View > 3D View (Global)*

And add these four items as the picture shows.

[image: ![config]

Basically:

- Add a *Switch to Move* on <kbd>Left Shift</kbd> *Press* and a *Confirm* on <kbd>Middle Mouse</kbd> *Release* to your *Rotate View Modal*.
- Add a *Switch to Rotate* on <kbd>Left Shift</kbd> *Release* and a *Confirm* on <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Middle Mouse</kbd> *Release* to your *Pan View Modal*.

Answer (score -2):

Got to *File > User Preferences > Input > 3D View > View 3D Rotate Modal* and add a new key combination

Set it to `Switch to Move` and add any key combination you like.

I did not succeed settings it to work with the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key though, it seems to not like "modifier keys" on their own, but most other combinations will probably work.

Comment: As you said, this doesn't work for modifier keys, so this unfortunately won't work for me