# Can Blender toggle camera orbit/rotate on keypress?

Tags: camera, shortcut

I'm new to Blender and one of the big hurdles for me is camera movement. I'm coming from 3ds Max where I'm used to pressing a keybind (CTRL-R) to enter an Orbit mode, in which left click and drag rotates the view and right click exits the mode. My question is, is there a way (settings or otherwise) I can get Blender to do the same?

I already know that I can set camera rotation/orbit to different keybinds, and that both 3ds Max and Blender will let you orbit with CTRL-Middle Mouse, but I've gotten so used to toggling it on/off instead of holding down a key. I foolishly tried to set camera rotation to left mouse in Blender but then it just orbited always and I couldn't select things. If I could somehow set orbit/rotate camera to left mouse and then a toggle keybind to turn it on and off I'd be set!

Comment: in my blender CTRL-Middle Mouse males the view "zoom" (just like the mouse wheel scroll)... what you mean by "camera orbit"?

Comment: Camera orbit is the Blender equivalent of View Rotate operator, or in Camera cases rotating the camera object. I think I've seen this asked around before.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56910/switching-between-pan-and-orbit-while-holding-mmb/56915#56915